# Showing that intersections are not defined

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I'm checking to see why intersections are not defined when looking at the class $A$ defined by:

$$ A = ON \cup [ON]^2\;,$$

where $ON$ is the class of ordinals and $[ON]^2$ the class of unordered pairs of distinct ordinals. Intersections are defined in $A$ if for any $x , y \in A$, we can find a $z \in A$ for which $\forall u \in A[u \in z \leftrightarrow u \in x \wedge  u \in y].$

Here's what I've been thinking so far:

I have to find some $x, y \in A$ with the intersection of $x$ and $y$ not being in $A$. If I'm taking $x$ and $y$ in $A$, then they have to either be ordinals, or ordered pairs of ordinals. Since the intersection of two ordinals is an ordinal, I can't choose both $x$ and $y$ to be ordinals. I'm guessing I have to let $x$ be an ordinal and $y$ be an ordered pair.

This is where I'm getting stuck. I've tried several choices for $x$ and $y$, with $x$ being an ordinal, and $y$ being an ordered pair of ordinals, but I'm not getting the result I want.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $ON$? I expect it to be the class of ordinals, but in that case $A=ON$, and it’s not a set.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: My apologies. $ON$ is the class of ordinals. I will mention that.

Comment: Then I don’t understand the question. $A$ isn’t a set: it’s just $ON$, since $\alpha,\beta\in ON$. And for any $x,y\in A$ we have $x\cap y=\min\{x,y\}\in A$, so intersection is defined.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I might not have worded it correctly. $A$ is taking the class of ordinals adding ordered pairs of ordinals to it. The question asked to show that $\cap^A$ is not defined. Where $\cap^A$ is defined if and only if for all $x, y \in A$, there is a unique $z \in A$ such that $\forall u \in A[ u \in z \leftrightarrow u \in x \wedge u \in y]$, in which case $x \cap^{\scriptsize{A}} y$ is that unique $z$.

Comment: Ah, okay: you want what might informally be written $ON\cup(ON\times ON)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem; I’m just glad to get it straightened out. I also have an answer for you, now that I understand the question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. I might have incorrectly stated something else. $A = ON \cup \{ \{\alpha, \beta\} : \alpha < \beta \in ON \}$, so I don't think we are considering ``ordered pairs" $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle$, but only pairs $\{\alpha, \beta\}$, where $\{ \alpha, \beta \} = \{ x : x = \alpha \vee x = \beta \}$.

Comment: Okay; I’ve revised my edit and answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: What is $2\cap\{1,2\}$? I’ve left the answer spoiler-protected.

> $2\cap\{1,2\}=\{0,1\}\cap\{1,2\}=\{1\}\notin A$.

Comment: I'm glad I was close. I actually had that answer, but I kept thinking that $2 \cap \{1, 2\}$ was $1$, not $\{1\}$, since $1$ is in both $\{0, 1\}$ and $\{1, 2\}$.

Comment: More generally, if $0<\alpha<\beta$, you’ll have a problem with $\beta\cap\{\alpha,\beta\}$, since it will be $\{\alpha\}$.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks again for your help.